# How to make a random number generator and copy it to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not much of a programmer yet, but I really want to make a text box that uses Javascript to randomly select characters, then output those characters into an HTML text field, with a button on the side to copy the characters in that text field.
[Here is a picture of what I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrzUU.png)

I found a couple of code snippets on the internet, but I am not sure how to put them all together.  If you could help me, I would appreciate it so much!

And if you are just passing by I hope that you have a fantastic day!

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 140px;
      background-color: #555;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      bottom: 150%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -75px;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 0.3s;
    }

    .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -5px;
      border-width: 5px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
    }

    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

**JAVASCRIPT (For "Copy to Clipboard" button)**

```
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  copyText.select();

  document.execCommand("Copy");

  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT (For Random Character generator)**
(Right now it only displays it in the console log)

```
var randomString = function(length) {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890!?";
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
}

var rs = randomString(10);

console.log("Our Random String Is: " + rs);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a copyText function that you can send your generated string into:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
function copyText(text) {
  input.value = text;
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  console.log("Copied");
}

const randomString = function(length) {
  let text = "";
  const possible = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890!?";
  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
}

input.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const rs = randomString(10);
  copyText(rs);
});
```

```html
<input>
```

(you have to click the input for the event to occur due to browser security)